# Vagrant hangs on Windows 7

Tags: vagrant

vagrant up seems to hang on Windows 7

My Vagrant file

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true

  config.vm.define "elk" do |elk|
    elk.vm.synced_folder "./www", "/var/www"
    elk.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "./Docker"
    end
  end
end
```

vagrant up --debug

```
==> elk: Syncing folders to the host VM...
 INFO machine: Calling action: sync_folders on provider VirtualBox (3c7dc34c-6fcf-4ace-87d1-0602b664e783)
DEBUG environment: Attempting to acquire process-lock: machine-action-740c202843bdf6334148bb69e000ec99
DEBUG environment: Attempting to acquire process-lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Acquired process lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Released process lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Acquired process lock: machine-action-740c202843bdf6334148bb69e000ec99
 INFO environment: Released process lock: machine-action-740c202843bdf6334148bb69e000ec99
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x3786018>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolders:0x38079d8>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\/powershell.EXE", "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found related vagrant issue here: 
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3139

Updating powershell to v3.0 solved the issue:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Comment: Upgrading PowerShell worked for me, but I also had to upgrade VirtualBox and restart my computer again after installing Vagrant.  To test what vagrant is complaining about use vagrant up --debug so you get some indication of what it is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: The solution described here: upgrade windows management framework (including powershell) worked for me. Yet over time, new versions exist. Instead of clicking the Microsoft link in this answer, which is now obsolete, I recommend searching for the most recent version of "Windows Management Framework". In my case: Vagrant version 2.0.1 & Windows Management Framework 5.1 for Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I updated to WMF in version 5.1 and it worked fine for me as well.