# Vagrant up doesn't work, doesn't return any errors (Windows 7)

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm working on a site running on the Roots WP stack and we're now planning on switching from xampp to vagrant. The issue is when I run "vagrant up", nothing happens. No errors, no output whatsoever, it just hangs until I exit the command. Running vagrant init creates a vagrantfile, but vagrant up does absolutely nothing.

I'm working on Windows 7 right now, on a work computer. I've used vagrant successfully in the past without issues.

```
    # -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "precise32"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: This post seems to be a duplicate. See this link for a complete solution by downloading Windows Management Framework for Windows 7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013526/vagrant-hangs-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

I’d had the same issue (Windows7 Pro SP1, VirtualBox 5.1.26, vagrant 1.9.7).
I’ have resolved this issue via downgrade vagrant to 1.9.6.

Comment: Same here. I had downgrade Vagrant to 1.9.6 to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If Vagrant commands are hanging on Windows because they're communicating to VirtualBox, this may be caused by a permissions issue with VirtualBox. This is easy to fix. Starting VirtualBox as a normal user or as an administrator will prevent you from using it in the opposite way. Please keep in mind that when Vagrant interacts with VirtualBox, it will interact with it with the same access level as the console running Vagrant.

To fix this issue, completely shut down all VirtualBox machines and GUIs. Wait a few seconds. Then, launch VirtualBox only with the access level you wish to use..

Answer (score 0):

Issue exists due to call to powershell within vagrant. This is still an issue with current (2.0.1) vagrant version.

Related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013526/vagrant-hangs-on-windows-7).

There are multiple solutions:

- Downgrade vagrant to 1.9.6
- Update powershell to higher version

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,too.
My environment is Vagrant 2.0.2 , virtualbox 5.2.6  and win 7.
And I finally solved it by updating powershell 2 to powershell 4.